# Queries without matches does not return null in firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I have a doubt, I am making queries in firebase, in the first case the data exists in the node and manages to enter .on and retrieves the data, in the second case the data does not exist in the node and it provokes that it does not enter a .on And I do not retrieve any information

[image]

As it is seen in the node I only have 1 data and it is the one that coincides with the first case, for the second case no longer enters the .on

```
        vm.settlements.child('liqui')
        .orderByChild('rut')
        .equalTo(employee.rut)
        .on('child_added', function(snapshot){
             vm.dates = snapshot.val();

        });
```

When queries are made with equalTo and there are no matches. Should snapshot return null?

Comment: When queries are made with equalTo and there are no matches. Should snapshot return null?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, snapshot will return null. But the app won't crash if you didn't pass the null to a variable.

Comment: Okay then. Updated. Why ask such question?

Comment: I am used to it if it is null or it contains data the function .on should return that data null or bjecto, but in this case only enter to .on if it finds coicidencias, if it does not find it it skips the .on, there should be a correct form To get null returns

Comment: Okay then. Did answer your problems?

Comment: Not in its entirety, change child added by value, and enter in .on in any of the cases delivering null

Comment: What are you trying to explain? I can''t understand

Comment: Excuse me it is very difficult to translate into English and to understand what I want to explain, but your answer helped me to understand my problem a lot

Comment: Okay sure, happy to help :)